# Alignment of environment inside enumeration

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, mdframed

I defined an environment to add notes, i.e. pieces of text that are not strictly relevant to the question at hand but perhaps still interesting to read, via

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    innerrightmargin=0pt
]{siderule}
\newenvironment{note}%
    {\begin{siderule}\textbf{Note:}}
    {\end{siderule}}
```

It works well except in one case: When inserting this environment into an enumeration, the side rule passes right through the enumeration label, like so.
[image]

Any ideas on how to modify the environment definition to fix this issue? I'd like the label `(a)` to be horizontally aligned with other labels in the list, and everything else to remain unchanged. I'd like the solution to be as elegant as possible. I feel like this shouldn't require any deep `TeX`-level coding or fiddling with literal values for different lengths.

The picture was created with this MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false
]{siderule}
\newenvironment{note}%
    {\begin{siderule}\textbf{Note:}}
    {\end{siderule}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{note}
\blindtext
\end{note}
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does specifying `innerleftmargin=0pt` option to the `\newmdenv` achieve the desired results?  If you want some padding on both sides use something like `leftmargin=-3pt, innerleftmargin=3pt`.  For the right margin use `innerrightmargin=0pt`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, `innerrightmargin=0pt` did the trick for the right edge. I'd prefer not to 'hard code' some random numerical values for the left margin, though. Isn't there a more elegant way to make the enumeration label heed the vertical side rule in its alignment?

Comment: If you are ok with the vertical line being right next to the text than just use `0pt` for the left margins. The `-3pt` and `3pt` effectively add up to zero, which is why the left margin of the text is aligned.

Answer (score 8):

You can control the  desired spacing with

```
leftmargin=-3pt, innerleftmargin=3pt, innerrightmargin=0pt,
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftmargin=-3pt, innerleftmargin=3pt, innerrightmargin=0pt,
    linecolor=red,
]{siderule}
\newenvironment{note}%
    {\begin{siderule}\textbf{Note:}}
    {\end{siderule}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{note}
\blindtext
\end{note}
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd really prefer a solution that does not involve manually adjusting offsets.

Comment: @Casimir: At some point you have to decide how far you want the vertical line from your text. If you are fine with it right next to your text just use `0pt`.

Comment: I'd prefer not to fiddle with the `innerleftmargin` at all. Surely, there should be a way to simply make the label heed the side rule in its alignment?

Comment: @Casimir: Yes. Set it to `0pt`.

Answer (score 2):

With this approach, I don't start the `note` environment inside the enumeration until I issue an `\leavevmode`.  That establishes the proper horizontal offset.  Unfortunately, it also begins the note environment 1+ lines lower.  In my original answe, I compensate with a `\vspace` before the `note` environment.  Howevr, because of compressible glue, the needed value of the `\vspace` was subject to change.

In this EDITED version, I save the `note` environment in a `\vbox` named `\blob`.  Then I output `\blob`  with 22.1367pt of it above the baseline.  I give the value explicitly as `21.1367pt`; however, one could in theory reproduce that value as some judicious combination of `\baselineskip`, `\topskip`, etc. My speculation is that the value can be obtained using `\setbox0=\hbox{1}\the\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip-\ht\strutbox+\ht0`, but I am just guessing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false
]{siderule}
\newenvironment{note}%
    {\begin{siderule}\textbf{Note:}}
    {\end{siderule}}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}
\blindtext
\end{note}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \leavevmode\savestack{\blob}{\vbox{\begin{note}
\blindtext
\end{note}}}\belowbaseline[-22.1367pt]{\blob}
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Could you explain what each of the commands/quantities in `\setbox0=\hbox{1}\the\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip-\ht\strutbox+\ht0` are? I don't really understand what's happening here.

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming that the whole `\leavevmode\savestack{\blob}{\vbox{\begin{note}
[text]
\end{note}}}\belowbaseline[-22.1367pt]{\blob}` could be moved into the environment definition so that `note` could still be invoked everywhere in the document with the same syntax, i.e. just `\begin{note} ... \end{note}`?

Comment: @Casimir I haven't looked at the code that makes up the `enumerate` environment, but I know that there are various vertical lengths that are applied at various times.  `\the\dimexpr` says to evaluate the following expression as a dimensional operation and print it out as text.  The dimensions are `\baselineskip` distance between text lines, `\topskip` an extra offset often applied at the beginning of list environments, `\ht\strutbox` the space of a line of text that falls above the baseline, `\ht0` the height of box 0, which contains, in this case, the number "1".

Comment: @Casimir No, I would not move the `\savestack` into the environment, because it is only intended as a fix for `note`s that appear in a list.  You would not want to apply that in normal text.  It might be possible to create a 2nd environment, call it `lnote`, that includes it, to be only used inside list environments.